# Electric field around a infinite plate with voltage $V$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, voltage

Say that you have an infinite plate uniformly charged with voltage V, and you want to calculate the electric field strength at some distance z away from the surface.  I know that you can calculate the electric field in relation to the sheet charge $\sigma$ as $E = \frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}$, but I don't know how to relate charge $\sigma$ and voltage V.

Answer (score 0):

Because an infinite sheet generates an infinite electric field, it doesn't really make sense to talk about a specific voltage for the sheet the way you can for finite objects.

For a finite object, we can get far enough away that the field of the object diminishes.  Therefore summing the potential change of a test charge as it moves through the electric field to an infinite distance away will find that it converges to a particular value.  This can be considered to be the voltage of the object.

This technique isn't possible for an infinite plate.  The electric field from such an object never diminishes at any distance, so the potential change never converges to a single value at infinity.  The best you could do would be to say that it has a voltage difference $V$ at a point some distance $d$ from the sheet (giving you the strength of the electric field).

Comment: Okay, that makes sense and explains at least partially why I was confused.  Perhaps the infinite plate simplification is not valid.  What about the electric field from a finite disk that is at voltage V?

Here is a link to what I am talking about:
http://www.physics.udel.edu/~watson/phys208/exercises/kevan/efield1.html

That link has a formula $E_x = f(\sigma)$.  How would you rewrite that formula as a function of voltage on the disk?

$E_x = 2\pi k\sigma\left(1-\frac{x}{(x^2+R^2)^{\frac{1}{2}})}\right)$

Comment: If you have $E_x$, integrate the field from the object to infinity.  That's the voltage of the object at infinity, or the potential change of a test charge along that path.

Answer (score 0):

For charges extending to infinity, potential at infinity cannot be taken to be zero. Therefore, you will have to take other zero potential reference point and define the potential. For an uniformly charged infinite sheet normal to z - axis, the potential must be proportional to z, the proportionality constant is the magnitude of the field.